# Как лучше реализовать структуру данных с вопросами у которых будет верный и неверный ответ?

Tags: c#

Тренируюсь в создании игр на Unity. Требуется чтобы у каждого вопроса были свои варианты ответа. Один верный со значением true, другие false. Это лучше всего сделать при помощи двумерного массива или есть варианты получше? Или же лучше будет хранить SQLite, таблице?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php словари возможно помогут вам определиться

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208779/373567

Answer (score 1):

Можешь сделать так:

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс варианта ответа
/// </summary>
class Variant
{
    public Variant(string name, bool isAnswer = false)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsAnswer = isAnswer;
    }

    //Содержимое варианта ответа
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Проверка на то, является ли ответом
    public bool IsAnswer { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Класс вопроса
/// </summary>
class Question
{
    //Название вопроса
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Список вариантов
    public List<Variant> Variants = new List<Variant>();

    public Question(string name, List<Variant> variants)
    {
        Name = name;
        Variants = variants;

        //Необязательно в Unity
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
        foreach (var variant in variants)
            Console.WriteLine(variant.Name);
    }

    //Метод для проверки ответа
    public bool CheckAnswer(Variant variant)
    {
        if (variant != null)
        {
            var checkedVariant = Variants.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == variant.Name); //Ищем наш вариант ответа в списке вариантов
            if (checkedVariant.IsAnswer == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Правильно");
                return true; //Если ответ, то правильно
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Неверно");
                return false; //Иначе, неверный ответ
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var variants = new List<Variant>()
{
    new Variant("Белый", true), //Правильный ответ
    new Variant("Красный"),
    new Variant("Синий")
};
var question = new Question("Какого цвета луна?", variants);

question.CheckAnswer(variants[0]); //Верно
question.CheckAnswer(variants[1]); //Неверно
```

Вообще. В Unity можно даже вручную настроить все это. Для этого есть специальный UI.

Хранить можешь как в SQLite так и в JSON. Если есть сервер, можешь подключаться к нему и уже с него брать вопросы.

Comment: `== true` можно убрать из логического выражения, и ничего не поменяется. `checkedVariant.IsAnswer` может вызвать `NullReferenceException`, если `FirstOrDefault` вернет `null`.

Comment: Еще судя по логике, метод `CheckAnswer` должен принимать `string`, а не `Variant`, иначе смысла в нем маловато.

Comment: Насчет `== true` понятно. Насчет `checkedVariand.IsAnswer` я ведь объявил ее как необязательную переменную `public Variant(string name, bool isAnswer = false)` (Но, думаю, все же стоит поставить логическое дерево для проверки на `null` и обработчик исключений).

Comment: А вот насчет `CheckAnswer`, думаю, лучше принимать `Variant`, т.к. уже в самом классе есть реализация для варианта ответа. И флажок на то, что он, правильный. Иначе придется менять логику проверки (ибо придется сравнивать текст).

Comment: Чтобы проверить ответ не нужен метод, достаточно проверить свойство у него.

Comment: А в чем чем преимущество проверки свойства? Все равно придется придется реализовывать конструкцию. И наверняка будет событие, которое будет обрабатываться при нажатии на вариант. Практически то же самое придется обрабатывать, что я написал. Поэтому, думаю, уместно использовать метод. (ИМХО)

Comment: SOLID - SRP читайте. Если класс отвечает за хранение данных, он не должен больше ни за что отвечать. Ваш метод не ошибка, но он явно не намсвоем месте.

Comment: Ok. Понял. Буду иметь ввиду.